# Primeng table p-table,set conditional column editable

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I am using Primeng p-table control in my angular 7 application.
Below is the html code I am using:

```
<p-table [value]="data" [reorderableColumns]="'true'" [columns]="cols">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>

        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pReorderableColumn>
            {{col.header}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td  [pEditableColumn] *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
            <p-cellEditor  *ngSwitchCase="'TYPE'">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
                <p-cellEditor *ngSwitchCase="'CEPCODE'">
                        <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                            <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                        </ng-template>
                        <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                            {{rowData[col.field]}}
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-cellEditor>
                    <p-cellEditor *ngSwitchCase="'HRS'">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                                <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                            </ng-template>
                            <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                                {{rowData[col.field]}}
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-cellEditor>

        </td>

    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

On Running application table looks like below:
[image]

In my above table Type column is not editable and all other columns are editable. I want to know how we can set [pEditableColumn] for td dynamically(if column is type then do not set [pEditableColumn])

Answer (score 2):

This feature was there in the earlier version of primeNG and was easy to implement, however, you can use the below approach.

You can add one property to column configuration like col.editable

**Component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  cols = [];
  data = [];
  constructor() {
    this.cols = [
      { header: "TYPE", field: "TYPE", editable: false },
      { header: "CEPCODE", field: "CEPCODE", editable: true },
      { header: "HRS", field: "HRS", editable: true }
    ];

    this.data = [{ HRS: "HRS1", TYPE: "OMEGA", CEPCODE: "YTMMETRE" }];
  }
}
```

Based on that you can change the template when you are dynamically adding the template.
**component.html**

```
<p-table [value]="data" [reorderableColumns]="'true'" [columns]="cols">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>

        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pReorderableColumn>
            {{col.header}}
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns" [pEditableColumn] [ngClass]="{'disable-td' : !col.editable}" >
              <div *ngIf="!col.editable">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
              </div>
              <p-cellEditor *ngIf="col.editable">
                      <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                          <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                      </ng-template>
                      <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                          {{rowData[col.field]}}
                      </ng-template>
              </p-cellEditor>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**component.scss**

```
.disable-td{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropdowns-bug-x4cuys)

Template code removed for brevity!

Comment: Yes we can do like you mentioned. But in your solution Cell navigation is not working as I required.For example if there are 2 rows then on tabbing from Hrs field I want focus should go to CEPCODE of next row. See the below fork URL:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dropdowns-bug-2pxskz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found the below workarround(inline editing working with cell navigation)

```
<p-table  (sortFunction)="customSort($event)" [customSort]="true" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="650px" class="png-table"
[value]="data" [reorderableColumns]="'false'" [resizableColumns]="'false'" [columns]="cols">
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)" [hidden]="col.hide"
            pResizableColumn pReorderableColumn [class]="col.filter?'sortable':'non-sortable'">
            {{col.headerName}}
            <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>

        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="filter-row" *ngIf="1==2">
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [hidden]="col.hide">
            <input class="filter-input" *ngIf="col.filter" pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, 'contains')">
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.type">
            <td *ngSwitchCase="'del'" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                <i class="fa fa-close delete-icon g-act-icon" (click)='deleteRow()'></i>
            </td>
            <td *ngSwitchCase="'edit'" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                <i class="fa fa-edit edit-icon g-act-icon" (click)='deleteRow()'></i>
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='type'"  [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
            <td [pEditableColumn] *ngSwitchCase="'cep'" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <p-inputMask (keyup)="onEnterCEP()" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" mask="aaaaaa-999-999"></p-inputMask>

                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td [hidden]="col.hide" *ngSwitchCase="'cb'" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
            <td *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='act'" [pEditableColumn]  [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td  [pEditableColumn] *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='com'" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td [pEditableColumn] *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='tsk'" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td  [pEditableColumn] *ngIf="!col.hide && col.type=='sco'" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td [pEditableColumn] *ngSwitchCase="'hrs'" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" >
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td [hidden]="col.hide" [pEditableColumn] *ngSwitchCase="'des'" [style.width.px]="getColumnWidth(col)">
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="rowData[col.field]" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{rowData[col.field]}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
    </tr>
</ng-template></p-table>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is actually an undocumented `pEditableColumnDisabled` boolean directive that can be used to control if a cell is editable or not.

Source: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/v12.2.3/src/app/components/table/table.ts#L3337

Using it would be something like `<td pEditableColumn [pEditableColumnDisabled]="!col.editable" *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">`.